# pygame KEYUP KEYDOWN events only once per frame?

Tags: input, python, pygame, keyboard

I've been playing around with pygame, and I ran into a bit of an odd issue with input on the pygame event queue. Consider the following test code:

```
import pygame as pg

def main():
    pg.init()
    pg.display.set_mode([640,480])
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    while True:
        clock.tick(1)
        events = pg.event.get()
        print("There are %d events in the queue." % len(events))
        for event in events:
            print(event)
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here I'm intentionally running the game loop just once per second. What I observe is that the pygame event queue can easily receive dozens of mouse-related events per frame, but only ever **a single** KEYDOWN **or** KEYUP event at a time.

This is the output after pressing four keys simultaneously and quickly pressing the left mouse button a few times at the same time:

```
There are 0 events in the queue.

There are 1 events in the queue.
<Event(5-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>

There are 8 events in the queue.
<Event(2-KeyDown {'unicode': 'f', 'key': 102, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 41})>
<Event(6-MouseButtonUp {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>
<Event(5-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>
<Event(6-MouseButtonUp {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>
<Event(5-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>
<Event(6-MouseButtonUp {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>
<Event(5-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>
<Event(6-MouseButtonUp {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>

There are 3 events in the queue.
<Event(2-KeyDown {'unicode': 'q', 'key': 113, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 24})>
<Event(5-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>
<Event(6-MouseButtonUp {'pos': (494, 392), 'button': 1})>

There are 1 events in the queue.
<Event(2-KeyDown {'unicode': 'e', 'key': 101, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 26})>

There are 1 events in the queue.
<Event(2-KeyDown {'unicode': 'w', 'key': 119, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 25})>

There are 1 events in the queue.
<Event(3-KeyUp {'key': 119, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 25})>

There are 1 events in the queue.
<Event(3-KeyUp {'key': 113, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 24})>

There are 1 events in the queue.
<Event(3-KeyUp {'key': 101, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 26})>

There are 1 events in the queue.
<Event(3-KeyUp {'key': 102, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 41})>

There are 0 events in the queue.
```

At 1 FPS, it takes pygame 8 seconds to process just 4 keypresses, one for each KEYUP and KEYDOWN signal. Is this intended behavior? Am I missing something here? It seems odd to me that pygame cannot register multiple keypresses per frame. I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to gamedev, so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. The events appear in the next frame for me. What OS, Python and pygame version do you use?

Comment: @skrx I'm working on Linux (Fedora 27, kernel 4.15.6) using python 3.6.4 with pygame 1.9.3. I just tested it on a Windows 7 installation a while ago on another PC and there it was indeed working fine (I should have probably done that sooner, my bad). Anyway, that gives me a starting point to test this on a few different setups and hopefully track down the source of the problem. Thanks for taking the time to test it.

Comment: Better post this to the [mailing list](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/info) to contact the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the function pygame.key.set_repeat(delay, interval) once before starting the infinite while loop.
I use as delay 1 and an interval of 25.

From the docs: [pygame.key module](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat)

> The delay is the number of milliseconds before the first repeated pygame.KEYDOWN will be sent.
>   After that another pygame.KEYDOWN will be sent every interval milliseconds.
>   When pygame is initialized the key repeat is disabled.

This is the equivalent of for example a key pressed event in Game Maker